# Javascript auto scroll on div

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to scroll at the end of the div so in my case I can see the last message of chat.
Here's what I have but it doesn't work, the scroll is actually on top of the div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var divChat = document.getElementById('chat');
divChat.scrollTop = divChat.scrollHeight;
</script>
<div id="chat" style="border-style:groove;overflow-y: auto; height:50%;">
<?php 
    $response = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM minichat');
    while ($rsp = $response->fetch())
    {
        echo '['.$rsp['date_message'].']'." <strong>".htmlspecialchars($rsp['pseudo'])
        ."</strong>: ".htmlspecialchars($rsp['message'])."<br>";
    }
?>
</div>
```

Thanks by advance for any help,

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
<div id="chat" style="border-style:groove;overflow-y: auto; height:50%;">
<?php 
    $response = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM minichat');
    while ($rsp = $response->fetch())
    {
      echo '['.$rsp['date_message'].']'."         <strong>".htmlspecialchars($rsp['pseudo'])
    ."</strong>: ".htmlspecialchars($rsp['message'])."<br>";
    }
?>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  var divChat = document.getElementById('chat');
  divChat.scrollTop = divChat.scrollHeight;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: In my case I just need to do it when the page is refreshed, wasn't it suppose to work ?

Comment: So you have to remove ".value" after the getElementById('chat')

Comment: Same as before :(

Comment: I am really supprised, perhaps it's not the divChat element that have a scroolBar but a child of it.

Comment: The property overflow-y should be scroll or nothing, because it's auto by default. Have you tried to put your script at the end of the body, after the declaration of your chat element ?

Comment: Yes, because the page is read from top to bottom by your browser and script are executed while they are read, so here when the script was read your element 'chat' wasn't existing.